# Get facebook friend list in yii2 framework

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, yii2-advanced-app

I am using **Yii2 Framework** and I have to get Facebook friend list in web-service, for this i am following this steps: 
[FB FriendList](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/5.0.0)

Tried this:

```
<?php
use yii\Facebook\Facebook; // facebook class
public function getFbUserListFB()
    {
        $fb = new Facebook([
          'app_id' => 'appID',
          'app_secret' => 'appSECRET',
          'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3'
          ]);
        $response = $fb->get('/me');
        print_r($response);
    }
?>
```

but getting this error:

```
{
  "name": "PHP Fatal Error",
  "message": "Class 'yii\Facebook\Facebook' not found",
  "code": 1,
  "type": "yii\base\ErrorException",
  "file": "/var/www/html/PROJECT/api/modules/v1/models/FILENAME.php",
  "line": 19,
  "stack-trace": [
    "#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()",
    "#1 {main}"
  ]
}
```

Facebook **sdk path is**:

```
/var/www/html/PROJECTNAME/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/<all-files-and-folder>
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi same error i faced in yii2, i solved like below..,
this code is in view, also no need to use namespace for sdk,

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
     'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
     'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
     'default_graph_version' => 'v3.0',
     'display' => 'popup',
]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email','manage_pages','instagram_basic','instagram_manage_insights']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/site/contact/', $permissions);
```

******login button

```
<a class="btn btn-sm-connect instagram" href="<?= $loginUrl?>" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('<?= $loginUrl?>','MyWindow',width=600,height=300); return false;>
```

> MyWindow=window.open(  --> this for open in a pop up model )

*** controller action code

```
public function actionContact() {

    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v3.0',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($helper); exit;
    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    if (!isset($accessToken)) {
        if ($helper->getError()) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
            echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
            echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
            echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
            echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
        } else {
            header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
            echo 'Bad request';
        }
        exit;
    }

// // Logged in
// echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
// var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

    $token = $accessToken->getValue();
    // echo $token;
    //curl request to fb

    $pageModel = new Pages();
    $followersModel = new Followers();
    $curl = new curl\Curl();
    $response = $curl->setGetParams([
                // 'fields' => 'fan_count,name',
                'access_token' => $token
            ])
            ->get('https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me/accounts');
    $pages = json_decode($response);
    $pagesList = json_decode(json_encode($pages), True);
    $serviceProvider = 'instagram';
```

.... remaining u can take care of it...

Answer (score 0):

In config, add the module:

```
'modules' => [
        'facebook' => [
            'class' => '\facebook\Module'
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: @bluto If you want to use the Facebook as a vendor module, you've to declare a class and a namespace, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511481/how-to-create-modules-in-yii2

Comment: Try importing with facebook\Facebook, quit yii from path.