# Trying to update composer in Yii2

Tags: php, composer-php, updates, yii2-advanced-app

I want to update the composer:

but i am getting following errors:

```
Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.4 requires ext-mongo >=1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.3 requires ext-mongo >=1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.2 requires ext-mongo >=1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.1 requires ext-mongo >=1.4.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.0 requires ext-mongo >=1.3.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-mongodb ~2.0.0 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-mongodb[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4].
```

this is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.4",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-imagine": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget": "~1.0",
        "2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget": "~1.1",
        "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "~5.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-mongodb": "~2.0.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

How can i solve this? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be related to your `php.ini` with missing `mongo.so` extension.

Even if you have it enabled already for php in browser, composer uses `php.ini` for cli.
**It's different `php.ini` file**.

You can find it via:

```
php --ini
```

There will be something like:

```
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Edit this file with sudo:

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

And complete the extension there (last line should be fine):

```
extension=mongo.so
```

Restart php and retry `composer install`.

It it works, you're done. If not, try to follow [mongo install guide](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.nix).

Comment: hey.. in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` there is no that externsion

Comment: and can you please see my one more question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235223/get-facebook-friend-list-in-yii2-framework

Comment: how can I do it via cmd ?

Answer (score 1):

you must install extention to your php . Refer this: http://php.net/manual/ru/mongo.installation.php

Comment: can you please explain how?

Comment: it is depended on your operation system

Comment: and i have seen taht in php.ini file mongo.so is enabled

Comment: if you can't fix your problem. We search other reasons okey

Comment: i found this.. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=195001
but not getting what to wat to say

Comment: one  minut i'm checking

Comment: i catch that , composer have different php.ini file, u must restart server

Comment: hey.. in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini there is no that externsion

Comment: sudo pecl install mongo  and enable   extension=mongo.so

Comment: where it will install? in composer?

Comment: if you don't install php developer with pear, u can use this cmd sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-cli php-pear

Comment: i got this:Installing '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mongo.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongo-1.6.11
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=mongo.so" to php.ini

Comment: you must add extention=mongo.so in your php.ini file and run cmd composer update

Comment: how to do it with sudo on windows ?

Answer (score 0):

add extension

```
extension=mongo.so
```

to file `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

then restart php

```
sudo service apapche restart
```

and retry your install compose command