# How to use the MODELS inside MODULES

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am new to yii2 and i want to learn yii2.
How to create **modules** and how to use **Models inside the Modules.**

I created controllers and views and also
i am able to access the controllers views like modules in **modules/controller/action**.

**http://localhost:8082/countries/custom/greet**

I tried and get the url working for controller and actions in **yii2** but models how to use inside the modules for accessing the database data using models

can you help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: add the use statement `use app\models\ModelName;` on top and call the model like `ModelName::find()->where()->all()` or provide full namespace when calling the model, `app\models\ModelName::find()->where()->all()`

Comment: can you explain with project structure like modules,controllers,views,models of yii2.can you share the link

Comment: umm your question is about accessing the models from within the module controller , and to access the model all you need to do is to add the namespace of the model in the controller whichever it is , either `module/controllers/SomeController` or `app\controller\SomeController`, and thats it to generate the module automatically you should use GII as suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511481/how-to-create-modules-in-yii2

Comment: The local URL in your post is only accessible from your machine, if you want other users to be able to help better, you could post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

On the top of the Controller, you should add an use statement. E.g. `use app\models\SomeModel;`. After that you can access the model from the entire Controller by calling `SomeModel::<<findStatement>>`.

Alternatively you can call `app\models\SomeModel::<<findStatement>>` inside the code. That is, of course, if you have put the models in the right place under models folder in your yii folder.