# Override model in yii2 for mdmsoft/yii2-admin

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

I want to override the model in mdmsoft plugin of yii2.
https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

it's a module, you have to create your own module inherent from mdm\admin\module.
This link on how create a new module
[How to create modules in YII2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511481/how-to-create-modules-in-yii2)

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-modules

and in your config add the path of your config.

Original config

```
'admin' => [
    'class' => 'mdm\admin\Module',
    ...
]
```

New Config

```
'admin' => [
        'class' => 'new_module_name_space\Module',
        ...
    ]
```

You can create your model extends from yii2-amdin

Comment: But I just want to override the model and not the entire module.

Comment: This will do the job, and if you give me a full case I can help you